# Adding/appending an agent to another agent

Tags: anylogic

I have this model where an agent- container that contains another agent type- boxes, arrives and then the boxes are unloaded and moves to some location. Once the container is empty, it's moved out. The model works just fine. Now I want to swap the boxes between containers instead of moving them to a fixes location.

in the container page I have an agent of type Boxes, a parameter for the number of boxes and a veritable for the location of the boxes. I also have a statechart that sends a message once the container is empty as follows:

```
if (Boxes.size() > 0){
    Shipment b = Boxes(0);
    b.box_location = this.getXYZ();
    remove_Boxes(b);
    get_Main().pieces.take(b);
    current_N_Boxes--;
}
```

I'm not sure what more information is needed to draw a complete picture of the model, but I'm more than happy to provide that when asked for

PS. in main I added a population of containers, and in the agent container I added a population of boxes. In the latter, one of the parameters is mycontainer- which is the container population in main. Currently I have that as "this" but I suspect that should be changed to other containers.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question/problem? :-)

Comment: So instead of removing the boxes from the containers and moving them to a node- which what I do right now, I want to swap boxes between containers